# How can I pass command line arguments to BBEdit for testing

Tags: argument-passing, bbedit

I'm writing a script that takes command line arguments. Using BBEdit 10.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.6.8, is there a way to setup BBEdit "Run" command so that it passes a set of test arguments?

My goal is to be able to setup a hotkey that I can hit and have it run the script for me with a set of arguments I've configured. I know one approach would be to code test arguments directly in the script itself, but I'd like to avoid that. It's too easy to forget they are there and commit them as changes.

I don't see a way in the "#!" dialog box itself. Perhaps there is a way to script it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of January 4, 2012, the response directly from Bare Bones is:

> At present, the only way you can pass arguments to a script is to use
>   a 'wrapper' e.g. a separate shell script or AppleScript which in turn
>   invokes the script with any desired arguments.

They have gotten other requests to add the feature. The support person expected it to ship in a future release.